# IBM Watson Studio notebooks not connecting via proxy

Tags: proxy, ibm-server

Using my instituite's net access which is through aproxy server, I can access my IBMCloud account, my dashboard, my projects, but when I go on to edit a notebook, the kernel just never connects. It keeps retrying and finally says:

```
Connecting to the notebook kernel is taking far longer than expected. The kernel will be automatically restarted.
```

When I try the same from my personal laptop using a non-proxied server, everything works fine. So I figure it's the proxy that's issue here.
Any fix for using IBM Watson Studio Notebooks using a proxy-server?

Answer (score 0):

I have never used IBM Watson Studio notebooks, but since it is based on Jupyter, setting up proxy for Jupyter should solve your problem. For example, [see this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36629707/using-jupyter-behind-a-proxy).

### Set proxy in notebook

Set proxy within your notebook

```
In [1]: import os
        os.environ['http_proxy'] = "http://user:passwd@host:port" 
        os.environ['https_proxy'] = "https://user:passwd@host:port" 
In [2]: import requests
        requests.get("http://google.com")
Out[2]: <Response [200]>
```

### Set your OS' proxy settings

In your Jupyter notebook

```
import sys,os,os.path
os.environ['http_proxy']="http://user:passwd@host:port"
os.environ['https_proxy']="http://user:passwd@host:port"
```

### Add proxy to Notebook Startup

Edit `~/.jupyter/profile_myserver/startup/00-startup.py` with proxy settings

```
import sys,os,os.path
os.environ['http_proxy']="http://proxy.example.com:80"
os.environ['https_proxy']="https://proxy.example.com:443"
```